# 「ᙏ̤̫」という合成文字がうさぎの顔に見えるように表示したい

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, font

環境
OS: OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
Safari: 9.1.2 11601.7.7
Chrome: 55.0.2883.95 64-bit
https://codepen.io/technuma/pen/BpBRjZ

```html
<h1>ᙏ̤̫ rabbit ᙏ̤̫</h1>
```

文字コード: UTF-8
表示したい文字: ᙏ̤̫
上のcodepenをMac

・ safari で開く場合
　正常に見える
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

・ chrome で開く場合
　文字化けする
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

という状態です。

どうしたら解消できますでしょうか。

Comment: ブラウザの挙動はOSやバージョンによって変化することがありますから、検証したOSやブラウザのバージョンを記載してください。またあなたが期待するものと、それがどう化けているのかがはっきり伝わるように、スクリーンショットも載せていただけるとわかりやすいと思います。

Comment: 僕の環境では再現できず(Chrome/Firefox/Vivaldi on linux)，一口に「文字化け」と広く呼ばれるものの中にはエンコーディングが間違ってる（多分本来の）文字化けとか，フォントが対応できてない時の豆腐とか，色々あって問題になっている状況がわからないので，スクリーンショットがあるとだいぶありがたいです．

Comment: それぞれ追加しました、ありがとうございます

Comment: なるほど、兎に見えるのですね。私の環境ではまた別の合成のされ方をしているので、豆腐にもならず、兎にもならずです。ちなみに兎の絵文字もあるようです。[](http://emojipedia.org/rabbit-face/) [](http://emojipedia.org/rabbit/)

Answer (score 18):

あなたがタイトル中に含められている文字(本文中のリンクは補助的な情報に止めるようにして、リンク先を見なくても質問が意味を成すようにしてください)は次の3つのUnicodeコード値からなる合成文字です。

> U+164F CANADIAN SYLLABICS CARRIER SO
>
> U+0324 COMBINING DIAERESIS BELOW
>
> U+032B COMBINING INVERTED DOUBLE ARCH BELOW

環境依存で読めない場合があることはわかっているのですから、質問の本文中では(せめてソースを確認してくれた人には)文字コードがわかるように記載した方が良かったでしょう。

ᙏ̤̫
↑
    `&#x164F;&#x0324;&#x032B;`

このような非標準の合成文字がどのように描画されるかと言うのは完全に環境依存で、Mac版のChromeのように豆腐が3つ並ぶ場合もあるでしょうし、合成されずに3つの字型が横に並ぶこともあるかもしれません。

どうしても、3つの文字を使って絵文字風の文字を(環境非依存に)表示したいのであれば、合成文字を使わずに別々の文字として記載した上で、CSS等を使って意図的に重ね合わせないといけないでしょう。

```css
  span.first {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  span.second {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.8em;
    margin-left: -1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  span.third {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.4em;
    top: 1em;
    width: 2.4em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
```

```html
<span class="first">&#x164F;</span><span class="second">&#x00A8;</span><span class="third">&#x23D6;</span>
```

(もっとうまいやり方はありそうですが、こんなものを記載した意図としては、「ここまではやりたくないよね」なので、こんなもんで。)

要はMacやiOSでは普通に入力・表示できる絵文字の一部がWindowsでは表示できないのと同じ理屈です。同じMacなのにSafariとChromeで動作が異なるのは、HTMLのレンダリングでは通常のテキスト描画エンジン丸々は使えないため、ブラウザだけの独自処理を行っている部分があるせいでしょう。(Chromeでもシステム側にテキスト表示を丸投げしているらしいタイトル部分では正常に表示されていますから。)

**環境非依存にしたいのなら、合成文字は使い物にならない**と覚えておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 質問内容を編集しました、ありがとうございます
合成文字の解析までやっていただいて感謝しております。
たしかにここまでは実装したくないと感じました...

Answer (score 0):

何語の文字なのでしょうか？ `Noto Sans Japanese`、`Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro`、`Meiryo`、`MS PGothic`等のフォントが指定されていますが日本語の文字ではないはずです。日本語で質問するよりも適切な言語で質問すべきです。
文字を不適切に図形のように扱うのであれば、それが意図通りに表示されないことは**文字化け**ではなく**力不足**ということになります。

最近では[Webフォントを自作してみる](http://akabeko.me/blog/2013/06/web-font/)のように図形をフォント化し、作成したWebフォントをブラウザーに読み込むことで意図した図形を表示することもあります。
[The Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)のようによく使われる図形が既にフォント化され公開されている場合もあります。